# Better way to parse String to Double in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to parse a Currency Formatted String back to Double and then back to String in Android like so:

```
                String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency().getSymbol());
                String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll(replaceable, "");

                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));
```

I was continually getting **java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""**

I finally wrapped this in a Try Catch block like so

```
                double parsed = 0.00;
                try {
                    parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));
```

Now it works as far the Android app no longer crashes, however this line of code pumps out many lines of exception so I am wondering if there is a better way I can parse the string into double and not have these many exceptions thrown because of the "" character. Below is a sample of the exceptions I am getting

Thanks for your time

[image: Java Exception]

Comment: If it's just empty Strings you're worried about, couldn't you just test for `""` before parsing it?

Comment: Its not just parsing for empty string, this is an event handler that is attached to Android EditText that watches for text changes, so when user enters 1595 for example it changes it to $15.95, so first you have to get the string and remove the currency and any space and then parse that into a Double and apply CurrencyFormatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
            double parsed;
            try {
                parsed = Double.parseDouble(stringValue);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                parsed = 0.00;
            }
```

Comment: Yes, it definetely works! Wow, learning something new everyday. At first it did not make sense to me but now I get it. Thanks